# Issue with getting user activity report through Microsoft Graph API (Graph Explorer)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a MS Teams report of User activity over the last 90 Days, however when I try to run the call: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserCounts(period='D90')` on Graph Explorer, it respond with an error `Failure - Status Code 0`. When I added parameter `?$format=application/json` at the end of the request, it responded successfully with data of the report in json format. However, I could not get anything from this response because it did not specify users' identities. Anyway to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`getTeamsUserActivityUserCounts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityusercounts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint reports aggregated counts by Team, not by User. To report on activity by User, you need to run the [`getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 452

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.teamsUserActivityUserDetail)", 
  "value": [
    {
      "reportRefreshDate": "2017-09-01", 
      "userPrincipalName": "userPrincipalName-value", 
      "lastActivityDate": "2017-09-01", 
      "isDeleted": false, 
      "deletedDate": null, 
      "assignedProducts": [
        "OFFICE 365 ENTERPRISE E5"
      ], 
      "teamChatMessageCount": 0, 
      "privateChatMessageCount": 49, 
      "callCount": 2, 
      "meetingCount": 0, 
      "hasOtherAction": true, 
      "reportPeriod": "7"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, this looks more promising as it contains UPN value. However, same error still occurs when I use your suggested command. On Chrome it returns a 200 status code with a broken image. On Edge it is still the Failure code similarly to the original post... Also, json is not supported.

Comment: That is correct, it does not support `JSON` at the moment. I believe the broken image is because it's returning a `302` which redirects you to the file (which Graph Explorer does not handle).

Comment: It seems to be alright now with Graph API beta, I think the issue just occurs with 1.0. Thanks very much Marc for your help!